Sobolev embedding on compact manifold without boundary
I am reading M. E. Taylor, "Partial Differential Equations III", Second Edition, Springer-Verlag, New York, (1996).
In chapter 13, section 2, in Prop. 2.3 and Prop. 2.4, one finds the following Sobolev embeddings: If $kp>d$ one has
\begin{equation}
H^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)\subset C(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)\,.
\end{equation}
If $kp<d$, it holds
\begin{equation}
H^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^d) \subset L^q(\mathbb{R}^d),\qquad 1/q= 1/p-k/d\,.
\end{equation}
I would like to have such embeddings on a compact manifold without boundary, e.g., a sphere. In the beginning of the chapter 13, it is written that instead of $\mathbb{R}^d$, one can have a compact manifold, possibly with (smooth) boundary, however, there is no proof as long as I read. I am more interested in case where $k$ could be non-integers.

I believe that everything you are asking about for integer $k$ is covered in Chapter 2 of Nonlinear analysis on manifolds: Sobolev spaces and inequalities by Hebey,. For non-integer $k$, is there even an agreed upon definition of fractional Sobolev spaces that don't have $p=2$? In this case, you can use spectral decomposition and the Laplace-Beltrami operator to define the right seminorms, but I'm not sure about the other cases.
